# Remote config con Angular

Tags: angular, firebase

Hola a todos como estan?

Estoy tratando de obtener una configuracion que he creado en remote config de firebase con mi aplicacion de **Angular 15**

La configuracion se llama "UsuariosPermitidos"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi aplicacion ya tengo configurado firebase porque lo utilizo para otras cosas, pero ahora necesito obtener esta configuracion y no he podido.

**app.module**

```js
    imports: [
        ...,
        AppRoutingModule,
        provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
        provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
        AngularFireRemoteConfigModule
    ],
```

**service**

```js
import { AngularFireRemoteConfig } from '@angular/fire/compat/remote-config';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

   constructor(
        private readonly firestore:Firestore = inject(Firestore),
        private remoteConfig: AngularFireRemoteConfig
   ) { }

   public getRemoteConfig(): any {
    return this.remoteConfig.getAll()
   }

  getFeatures():Observable<IFeature[]>{
    const featureRef = collection(this.firestore,this.collectionName)
    return collectionData(featureRef,{idField:'id'}) as Observable<IFeature[]>
  }
}
```

**El error que da**, es que no hay ningun providers para "AngularFireRemoteConfig"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si es la forma correcta la que estoy usando ,pero no he encontrado otra. (las que encontre eran viejas con modulos que ya no existen en Angular 15)